# Create Div on the fly, above the others

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

Every second this script will open a page using AJAX and return the contents into a new div on this page, which it creates on the fly. But unfortunatly, they div's go under each other. And I would like to create each new div at the top. I don't really want to use jquery or anything similar.

Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated, I'm not very confident with JS so if it's not obvious why, could you please give me a small explanation too. :) Thanks

```
function timedCount()
{
  min = Math.floor(s/60);
  sec = s-(min*60);
  if(sec < 10) { sec = '0'+sec; }
  if(min >= 60) { min = min-15; }
  if(quit == 0) { document.getElementById('mTime').innerHTML = min+':'+sec; }
  s=s+1;
  var ajaxRequest;
  try { ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); }  catch (e){
    try{ ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {
      try{ ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e){
        alert("Your browser broke!");
  return false;
      }
    }
  }
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.responseText != '')
   {
        if(ajaxRequest.responseText == 'HT') {
        document.getElementById('mTime').innerHTML = 'Half Time';
        t=setTimeout("timedCount()",(3600-s)*1000);
        quit=1;
       return;
    }
    if(ajaxRequest.responseText == 'FT') {
      document.getElementById('mTime').innerHTML = 'Full Time';
      quit=1;
      return;
    }
    el = document.createElement('rep'+i);
    el.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText +'<br>';
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(el);
    i=i+1;
  }
}
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "getMatch.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `el = document.createElement('rep'+i);`? This will create elements that look like `<rep12></rep12>`. I'm guessing you want `el = document.createElement('div'); el.id = rep + i;` or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore) function

```
var parent = document.getElementById('container');
parent.insertBefore(el, parent.firstChild);
```

Note that if parent is empty, and parent.firstChild is therefore null, then el will be inserted at the end of parent, which is what you'd want.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using `insertBefore` ?

You could change the line:

```
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(el);
```

by

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.insertBefore(el, container.firstChild);
```

`container.firstChild` will give you a reference to the first element within container and put `el` before it.

Answer (score 1):

The appendChild method always adds the new node at the **end** of the collection which is why it appears at the botttom - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535934(v=VS.85).aspx

Use the insertBefore method documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535934(v=VS.85).aspx. You can use document.getElementById('container').firstChild as the second argument

Comment: Apologies for the lack of code comment. I've upvoted the other solutions as they are entirely correct. Typing on a tablet sucks and takes forever!

Answer (score 0):

usually if I really want to put a div on top of all other elements I do use the css position and z-index like:

```
div{
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
}
```

:)